# Different layout between Mac and Windows/Linux (same *.ui files)

Tags: c++, linux, windows, macos, qt

I'm deploying my application with Qt Framework.
The behaviour of layout is equal in Windows and Linux; and if I resize the windows the layout adapts. This doesn't happen in Mac OS. To develop for Mac, I'm using a virtual machine (the resolution is 1024x768), but, when I try to start my bundle in a "true" Mac (resolution's biggest) the result is terrible!

I put some pictures:

MAC - virtual machine (1024x768) - First tab (OK)
[image: MAC - virtual machine (1024x768) - First tab (OK)]

MAC - virtual machine (1024x768) - Second tab (Not OK)** 
[image: MAC - virtual machine (1024x768) - Second tab (Not OK)]

**The second tab "Rubrica Contatti" is designed like the first tab "Ricettario". In designer the second tab seems ok, at runtime no!

I have tried to create a new project for test.
I've set the Central Widget with Form Layout.
I've created 2 Widgets that contain these items (each widget has a Grid Layout):

- LineEdit
- ComboBox
- GroupBox (with Grid Layout) containing 2 labels and 2 checkboxes

All these three items are clustered in vertical layout. I put the left widget in **QSizePolicy::Minimum** and the right one in **QSizePolicy::Preferred**. In Qt Designer the left panel is smaller and the right one is horizontally enlarged. When I start the app, both widget have the same width and are in the center of the window.

> **Note:**
>   When I open any project, I get this text in *"General Messages"* .

```
Warnings while parsing QML type information of /Users/denny/Qt/5.5/clang_64/qml:  
<dump of /Users/denny/Qt/5.5/clang_64/qml>:1:24: Reading only version 1.1 parts.  
<dump of /Users/denny/Qt/5.5/clang_64/qml>:10:5: Expected only Component and ModuleApi objects definitions.
```

Could it be the cause?

Comment: [MAC - virtual machine (1024x768) - Second tab in Qt Designer - It seems OK](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FcQ0w.png)      [Linux - (1366x768) - Layout OK (like in Windows)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/C9M3Q.png)                [True MAC - (???) - Layout seems fixed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/SsYiG.jpg)                            [True MAC - (???) - In this Dialog I don't see some elements](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bl2Bm.jpg)

Comment: Please describe the issue instead of just referring to the pictures, such as: The width didn't fill up as expected or the buttons are half the size they should be, etc.  If it is a problem with not filling the area, you need to set the layout. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html

Comment: Sorry... I've set the layout from qt designer. In fact, on Windows and Linux the area is filled

Comment: @DennyVavalà what do you expect? Show the second tab as it should be. Are you using horizontal spacer items?

Comment: In my comment there are links to other pictures... [Linux (1366x768) - Second Tab "Rubrica Contatti"] (http://i.stack.imgur.com/C9M3Q.png) <--- This is correct    . No, I use form and grid layout

Answer (score 3):

The problem remains, but it solved so (for now)...

```
QApplication::setStyle("fusion");
```

My app won't use Mac Themes, but it will use Fusion Theme...

> **Note:**
>   The graphic is uglier, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

It happens because, different styles use different expanding policies.
For example the QFormLayout deals with enum QFormLayout::FieldGrowthPolicy.

`QFormLayout::FieldsStayAtSizeHint`  - This is the default for QMacStyle.

`QFormLayout::AllNonFixedFieldsGrow` - This is the default policy for most styles.

`QFormLayout::ExpandingFieldsGrow`   - This is the default policy for Plastique.

Answer (score 0):

- For the panel on the left, set the horizontal [size policies](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum) to
  `QSizePolicy::Minimum`. It means *this widget can be larger but there is no point expanding it*.
- For the panel on the right, set the horizontal size policies to
  `QSizePolicy::Preferred`. It means *if there is space to grow further use it*.

Put the left panel widget in a single widget, the right panel widgets in another widget, and use a form layout. The form layout usually set the right size policies for left and right.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Tomorrow I will try and then I'll let you know

Comment: The wonderful thing is that if I click on **Tools > Form Editor > Preview** then I see perfect layout